# How to store the functions or the values of the function and reuse them after browser refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am storing an object named session into my localStorage for further use after browser refresh. but i have lot of functions associated to it such as session.getUserCount(), session.getPeerIds() and so on. i am using .toString() to store it into the local storage, with the help of this i am able to retrieve the direct vatiables such as session.id, session.initiator but all the functions now returning the value as null.

Please help me in storing the values of all the functions in some good way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement inner `data` json object, `fromJSON` and `toJSON` methods in `Session` class

But you need to remember that `data` object can only save `number`, `string`, `null`, `array` and plain `object`

```js
class Session {
    constructor(id) {
        this.data = {
            id: id,
            createdAt: Date.now(),
            userCount: 0,
            user: {
               name: 'foo',
               likeIds: [1, 56]
            }
        }
    }
    getUserCount() {
        return this.data.userCount;
    }
  
    fromJSON(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    toJSON() {
        return this.data;
    }
}


// Usage
var session = new Session(1);
localStorage.abc = JSON.stringify(session);

var restoredSession = new Session();
try {
    restoredSession.fromJSON(JSON.parse(localStorage.abc));
} catch (e) {
    console.error('JSON parse error');
}

console.log(restoredSession);
```